# Rails html file sent as pdf

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf, printing

I have a printable invoice system on my website. This is done with a print.html.erb version of my invoice show page, which is embedded in an iframe and then printed using javascript `$("#print-frame").get(0).contentWindow.print();`. So it essentially prints the print.html.erb file.

I want to be able to send the *exact same* invoice as a pdf in an email from a controller. In other words, it should look exactly like the print preview of this page (which can be previewed using finder in pdf if you use Firefox)

(print.html.erb has inline stylesheets)

How?

Answer (score 0):

We use `acts_as_flying_saucer` for this - it's a rails wrapper for `flying_saucer` which is a java app that converts html pages to pdfs.

https://github.com/amardaxini/acts_as_flying_saucer

When you print your page, it will use any stylesheets with media set to "print" or "all".  You would set up a template for rendering to pdf which uses the same stylesheets.  You can then view the page in the browser with this template - it should look like your print preview.  Then you can render the page to pdf confident that what you see is what you get.  You don't need to go through this process every time, just when you're first setting it up really, but it's good as you can test the formatting in a web page without having to render to pdf every time.

Couple of potential gotchas:

- Your pages need to pass a strict XHTML test.  They should anyway, but in the browser you can get away with being a bit sloppy, but not here.  `xmllint` is handy for debugging, there are also various browser plugins for XHTML validation.
- when you have locally sourced images in your page, `<img>` tags will need to be modified to use a filesystem location instead of a path relative to your public folder as you would normally.